# JSON data is not showing in my app

Tags: java, android, json

Sir i am very very noob in android programing. recently i am trying to create api link from [yts.arg](https://yts.ag/api#list_movies) and trying to parse data in my application so that i can present list of movies in my app. i tried everything but i always get this exception org.json.JSONException: No value found..
in below i am adding everything pls i need help....i am new in stack overflow i trying my best to asking a gd question..
**From this activity i am calling my Fragment:**

```
package com.example.mehadi.pravashsirmat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTab;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabListener;

public class econd extends AppCompatActivity implements MaterialTabListener {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    MaterialTabHost materialTabHost;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_econd);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ecotoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        materialTabHost = (MaterialTabHost) findViewById(R.id.materialTabHost);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpagerfreco);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                materialTabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            materialTabHost.addTab(materialTabHost.newTab().setIcon(adapter.geticon(i)).setTabListener(this));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

           // NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab tab) {

    }

    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public int[] pcons = {R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp1_user, R.drawable.ic_add_alert_black_24dp_alert, R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp_home};

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (position == 0) {
                fragment = new Fragment_a();
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                fragment = new Fragment_b();
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                fragment = new Fragment_c();
            }
           // Myfragment myfragment=new Myfragment();

           // Myfragment myfragment=Myfragment.getInstance(position);
            //myfragment.getInstance(position);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs)[position];
        }

        public Drawable geticon(int position) {
            return getResources().getDrawable(pcons[position]);
        }

    }
}
```

From this fragment i am calling my api:

```
package com.example.mehadi.pravashsirmat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by MEHADI on 8/5/2016.
 */
public class Fragment_a extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.for_frag_a, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView_fr_a);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://yts.ag/api/v2/list_movies.json",
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //textView.setText(response.toString());
                        parseJasonresponse(response);
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(request);

        return layout;
    }

    public void parseJasonresponse(JSONObject response) {
        if (response == null || response.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        try {
          StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();

            JSONObject arrayob = response.getJSONObject("data:");
            JSONArray arrayobfrmovies = arrayob.getJSONArray("movies:");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayobfrmovies.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentmovies =arrayobfrmovies.getJSONObject(i);
                String Title = currentmovies.getString("title:");
                data.append(Title + "\n");
            }
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), data.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            textView.setText("Error=" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

i am also adding jason code for movie list:

https://yts.ag/api/v2/list_movies.json

Comment: First of all, it is JSON not Jason.

Comment: Who's Jason and what are you doing with his data?

Comment: Ha ha nice one  @AlexLogan ..   Remove ":" character from all you key's ie "data:" becomes "data"  .

Comment: ha ha sorry guys its json....

Comment: thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that its "data" and "movies" and "title" in JSON link posted.So change

"data:" with "data" and

"movies:" with "movies" and

"title:" with "title"
i.e. change

```
JSONObject arrayob = response.getJSONObject("data:");
            JSONArray arrayobfrmovies = arrayob.getJSONArray("movies:");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayobfrmovies.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentmovies =arrayobfrmovies.getJSONObject(i);
                String Title = currentmovies.getString("title:");
                data.append(Title + "\n");
            }
```

with

```
JSONObject arrayob = response.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONArray arrayobfrmovies = arrayob.getJSONArray("movies");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayobfrmovies.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentmovies =arrayobfrmovies.getJSONObject(i);
                String Title = currentmovies.getString("title");
                data.append(Title + "\n");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
JSONObject arrayob = response.getJSONObject("data:");
    JSONArray arrayobfrmovies = arrayob.getJSONArray("movies:");
```

with

```
JSONObject arrayob = response.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONArray arrayobfrmovies = arrayob.getJSONArray("movies");
```

Remove semicolon from **movies** and **data**.You have to provide excat json object name